# How to prevent a user from switching off wifi - Android phone

Tags: android, mobile, wifi

I'm looking for a way / app to prevent users from accidentally switching off the WiFi on Android phones.

The scenario is :

Android phones being used in a care home with a sip client to the PBX and various messaging and care management apps installed.  All this fails if the user accidentally switches off the WiFi - which is a common occurance.  So....I'm looking for a way to effective remove the option the switch off the WiFi.

There are many answers and apps which are a "keep alive" but that's not the solution the problem we have.

We do also use mobicontrol too if that helps too ?

Answer (score 0):

I would try with `Broadcast Receiver`. When app notices WIFI state change, inform user (e.g. dialog) to turn the WIFI on again.

I think it's impossible to completely prevent users from turning off any option on non-rooted device.